# How to see the Generic Array's name while debugging?

Tags: arrays, delphi, generics, delphi-xe7

I started using a lot of generics but now I find it harder and harder to debug, to know which array is actually begin worked on. See example:

```
Type
  TData = record
      DataID:integer;
      DataName:string;
  end;

var DataArr1,DataArr2,DataArr3:TArray<TData>;

procedure WorkOnData(Data:TArray<TData>);
begin
  if Data = DataArr1 then // <-- PARKING HERE ON DEBUG I CAN SEE ARRAY DATA, BUT NOT WHICH ARRAY IT IS
    ProcessA(DataArr1)
  else if Data = DataArr2 then
    ProcessB(DataArr2)
  else if Data = DataArr3 then
    ProcessC(DataArr3);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender = Button1 then
    WorkOnData(DataArr1)
  else if Sender = Button2 then
    WorkOnData(DataArr2)
  else if Sender = Button3 then
    WorkOnData(DataArr3);
end;
```

So, I can identify the array by comparison to get True/False:

```
Data = DataArr1
```

but, this doesn't give me info which array it is, before the comparison. So, I would need to put breakpoints after each comparison to know which one is True.

These obviously don't work:

```
Data.Name

TArray<Data>.Name
```

**Is there any other way to know which array has been passed that I can see in debugger (Watch)?**

---

**Answer/Solution**:

For anybody who faces the same problem, question: As Remy says in accepted answer that what I would like to achieve, is not possible. OK, now the quick workaround is to put the comparison (`Data = DataArr1`) into Watch and see which one resolves to True. Not best, but still usable as now we can see which array is actually being used.

Comment: This code is *so wrong*. It's not properly doing anything, much less using generics. Proper code wouldn't need to use a `case` or `if` to branch to different code; it would use a method in a base class that could be overridden in each subclass to implement specific behavior. By having to use the multiple tests, you've defeated the entire purpose of using generics.

Comment: `A := TArray<Integer>.Create(0); B := A;` What is the name the array, A or B? Arrays don't have names. Switching behaviour on the identity of the array seems wrong. Does your real code look like this.

Comment: I do use code really very similar. I reduced the number of methods that do the same thing on different arrays by 90%.I grouped arrays into the most common array and as they are all of the same type, and using TArray<>, I can now call single method for all of them and just apply different code to the different record fields, and common fields are handled with same code. Works great.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm not using classes, yet. when I do, all this will be redundant, but right now, this is next step from previous situation, where each array had it's own method, doing 90% of the same things for all arrays. Generics, even though not used optimally, help me a lot.

Comment: This design is really bad. All those if statements.

Comment: I'm not too fond of CASE statements, so IFs are good for me - and they fit perfectly here. As said, this implementation drastically reduces the number of code lines. When it's time for next improvement, when I learn how to do it the right way, I'll probably feel the same as you.

Comment: It makes no sense to refactor badly in order to reduce the lines of code. If you're going to refactor, do it properly; it's a waste of time to reimplement and retest working code in order to replace it with more poor quality code.

Comment: @KenWhite Good advice, I agree with you! You should've seen the previous code - a total mess. Step by step into the right direction and refactoring duplicated arrays with common arrays defined with TArray<> help a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no variable names once the code gets compiled.  When you debug `WorkOnData()`, the only variable name it can display is `Data`, and there is no way for the debugger to know what `Data` is pointing at without evaluating an expression that you provide.  So no, what you are asking for is basically not possible.

What you would likely have to do is wrap your array inside of another `record` that has a `Name` string field, and then pass that record around as needed. When you inspect it in the debugger, you would see its `Name` value.

Comment: If you want to identify these arrays by name then yes, give them a name. However, it is exceedingly likely that giving them a name will just make your code unwieldy and clunky and bring no benefit at all. So, very likely, don't do what Remy says in the final paragraph. Almost certainly the way forward will be to write the code so that it isn't composed of function after function containing large if statements. Once you get the code factored correctly, you won't want to associate a name to each array.

Comment: The question is more geared towards what was unknown to me and didn't find anything by searching through resources. I assume the answer is really No - the way I have them setup now. Not a big deal, the usage of arrays like this outweighs the need for knowing all the details in debugging. There's a workaround, I can just put the comparisons into Watch and see which one resolves to True: `Data = DataArr1`.